# How to add array inside select statement of mysql in php(laravel)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am trying to add array inside the select statement in laravel,
this is the sample data,please check the follow snipplet,

```html
    $message =["messages"=>[ 
                            ["attachment"=>
                              ["type"=>"template","payload"=>
                                ["template_type"=>"list","top_element_style"=>"large","elements"=>
                                  [
                                    ["title"=>"test","image_url"=> "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/375/0*sepg7sXXe3zcmGvZ.png","subtitle"=>"Soft white cotton t-shirt is back in style","buttons" =>
                                      [
                                        ["type"=>"web_url","url"=>"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/buy_item?item_id=101","title"=>"buy item"]
                                      ]
                                    ]
                                    ,
                                    ["title"=>"test","image_url"=> "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/375/0*sepg7sXXe3zcmGvZ.png","subtitle"=>"Soft white cotton t-shirt is back in style","buttons" =>
                                       [
                                         ["type"=>"web_url","url"=>"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/buy_item?item_id=101","title"=>"buy item"]]
                                     ]

                                    ]
                                ]     
                            
                              ]
                           ]
                          ]
              ];
```

And when i extract from the database in laravel,I can able to do only until subtitle, I can't do the buttons parts

```html
  ["type"=>"web_url","url"=>"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/buy_item?item_id=101","title"=>"buy item"]
```

, here is my tried,

```html
    $message =["messages"=>[ 
                            ["attachment"=>
                              ["type"=>"template","payload"=>
                                ["template_type"=>"list","top_element_style"=>"large","elements"=>
                                  [
                                    Fabric::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$search_term%")
                                     ->select('title','postdate as image_url',"company_name as subtitle"
                                      )->get()
                                    ]
                                ]     
                            
                              ]
                           ]
                          ]
              ];
```

I have another fields for the buttons array fields for each, don't know how to add in select statement. Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method on Eloquent models returns a collection but it seems you're looking for an array.

So just modify your code like so:

```
Fabric::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$search_term%")
       ->select('title','postdate as image_url',"company_name as subtitle")
       ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Hi bro, I would like to do the last parts which is buttons and a list of arrays, can u see the sample data has the data after subtitle, my code just finished till the subtitle.